# Correct PowerShell Syntax for extracting node name from XML

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use dot notation in Powershell to return the node name G-VDS-ENC001.  Here is the XML sample:

```
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Enclave id="NEW">
<Enclave id="OLD">
<device>
  <name>G-VDS-GooD</name>
  <type>VoIP</type>
  <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
  <inform>PEM</inform>
  <outform>PEM</outform>
  <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
</device>
<device>
  <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
  <type>VoIP</type>
  <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
  <cert>
    <inform>PEM</inform>
    <outform>PEM</outform>
    <type>WebServer</type>
    <pwd>password</pwd>
    <altSubject />
  </cert>
  <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
</device>
<device>
  <name>G-VDS-ENC002</name>
  <type>VoIP</type>
  <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
  <cert>
    <inform>PEM</inform>
    <outform>PEM</outform>
    <type>WebServer</type>
    <pwd>password</pwd>
    <altSubject />
  </cert>
  <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
</device>
```

Here is the syntax of the PowerShell code I'm using:

```
$Name = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("//Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"OLD`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]").get_Innertext()
```

It returns:

```
G-VDS-ENC001VoIPVoice2NetworkPEMPEMWebServerpassword0
```

I just want it to simply return:

```
G-VDS-ENC001
```

Can anyone help me figure out the correct syntax?

Comment: Your sample xml isn't *quite* valid - I think you need to remove the ```<Enclave id="NEW">``` (or close it properly) and tack this onto the end ```</Enclave></Configuration>```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mostly there, but your xpath is selecting the `<device>` node:

```xml
  <device>
    <name>G-VDS-ENC001</name>
    <type>VoIP</type>
    <vlan>Voice2Network</vlan>
    <cert>
      <inform>PEM</inform>
      <outform>PEM</outform>
      <type>WebServer</type>
      <pwd>password</pwd>
      <altSubject />
    </cert>
    <RequireCert>0</RequireCert>
  </device>
```

so `InnerText` returns the concatenated text from *all* the child nodes.

What you want instead is:

```
$device = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("//Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"OLD`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]")
$name   = $device.name;
```

You can fold this into one line if you like:

```
$name = $FileOriginal.SelectSingleNode("//Configuration/Enclave[@id = `"OLD`"]/device[name[contains(text(), 'G-VDS-ENC')]]").name;
```